# How to load data (images) from different folders and subfolders in python

Tags: python, image, directory

I am trying a problem on the dataset DRISHTI-GS. I want to use the image (from training) and cup seg and disc seg image (from softmap) and implement a CNN model on it. The Ground Truth (GT) subfolder consists of 52 subfolders each corresponding to the 52 images in the other folder named Images (which is a subfolder of training). The subfolder in GT has 3 subfolders in it out of which subfolder softmap has two images that I need to load these images. I have given the layout of the subfolders in the image below if more details are needed. I hope that someone can help me with some concrete codes or some useful materials.

(*Basically want to list and filter all files with .jpg or .png extensions, in the main directory and in all its sub-directories.*)

[image: Layout of the subfolders]

Answer (score 0):

You can find all files in the current directory with the following code from [stackabuse](https://stackabuse.com/python-list-files-in-a-directory).

```py
import os

for root, dirs, files in os.walk("."):
    for filename in files:
        print(filename)
```

If you want to find only image files like `jpg` files, you can filter them like below:

```py
import os

for root, dirs, files in os.walk("."):
    for filename in files:
       if filename.endswith(".jpg"):
           # Process the file
```

Comment: Plenty of `os.walk` examples here on StackOverflow - Can you revise your link?

Comment: Got to the root folder of images (here `DRISHTI-GS`) and run this code. Also, I said you can filter your output with `endswith` method. Instead of relative code you can use absolute path.

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood your question correctly, I think something like this is what you're looking for (haven't tested this, but it should work)

```
import glob

paths = glob.glob("DRISHTI_GS/Drishti-GS1_files/Training/GT/**/SoftMap/*.png")
print(paths)
```

This will yield a list of strings, where each string is a path to an image. This relative-path pattern assumes that `DRISHTI_GS` is in the current working directory. You can also give it an absolute path.

The `**` in the glob-pattern indicates all immediate subfolders, regardless of their name.

The `*.png` represents the images of any name. In this case, it will only capture PNG-images. You didn't specify what format the images are - if they aren't PNGs, simply change the pattern to `*.jpg`, etc.